# date comparsion with date_format doesn't do as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I have a query that works fine, but for some reason today it doesn't and I suspected it has something to do with month change.

This query :

```
select 
if((date_format("28/04/13","%d/%m/%y") < date_format(NOW(),"%d/%m/%y")),'ok','not ok')
```

Will print `not ok` though the term should meet.

My value isn't really a string it's a `TIMESTAMP` column.

Note : i want it to show `ok` only when a day has passed,henceforth the `date_format`
My real query has those parameters in the `where` clause to get records if the date is not today and not today after 6. This is the full clause that doesn't operate :

```
and ifnull(date_format(a.daily_check,"%d/%m/%y"),
date_format(now()- interval 2 day,"%d/%m/%y")) < NOW()
and ifnull(date_format(a.daily_check,"%d/%m/%y 06:00"),
now()- interval 2 day) < date_format(NOW(),"%d/%m/%y %h:%I")
```

Any one knows why?

I'm on MySql Version 5.5.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't use `DATE_FORMAT()` but instead `STR_TO_DATE()`

```
IF(STR_TO_DATE('28/04/13', '%d/%m/%y') < CURDATE(), 'ok', 'not ok')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11617)

**DATE_FORMAT()** => date to string 
**STR_TO_DATE()** => string to date

Your problem is that since you use `date_format` a string comparsion occoures and not date. Either wrap it in `str_to_time` or change your logic

Comment: Ya both the value of the string is from a date column, its not a string it was just for the example, and using  date_format still doesn't work.

Comment: if it was a date, neither of them is needed.

Comment: Yeah i guess i forgot to mention i want it to show `ok` only when a day has passed, sorry.

Comment: can you give sample records? your current query should work if those columns are date, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/11622

Comment: Maybe there's a difference between timestamp and date? because it's timestamp. And consider it a simple table with 1 column with the value `2013-04-28 10:39:29`, as it's the only column used in this case. and the fiddle u provided is different then the query i'm running.

Comment: can you give sample records in the fiddle? 3-4 is just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but I'm not fermilier with sqlfiddle thus no idea how to provide records.

Comment: Well I solved it thanks to your note that date_format converts to string, the problem was it compared strings in the end, so i wrapped the date_format with `str_to_date` and then it worked. Please edit your question with the info about that and i'll accept it.